# Odoo - one2many relation - updating fields on child table

Tags: model, odoo, updating, one2many

I have a main model with a one2many field, linked to a secondary model, which also has a one2many field, linked to a third model.

How can I update values on the third model using onchange event of a field on the main model?

This is a short version of the question:
[ODOO - How to update two levels o2m fileds relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63782828/odoo-how-to-update-two-levels-o2m-fileds-relation)